# Synaptic wants to remove a lot of packages when I try to upgrade a program

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, lubuntu, synaptic

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 and I want to upgrade *some* programs, so I've added 16.04 repositories to my sources.list.

Now, when I try to upgrade e.g. GIMP or TexWorks, it puts *a lot* of stuff on "To be removed" list (stuff like alsa, cups, some programs I have installed,...). It doesn't seem to be related to unmet dependencies, because it does the same when I try to install some small random programs with just a few dependencies.

How can I upgrade/install (new versions of) some programs **without** upgrading the whole system?

I would like to only upgrade the packages such that newer versions of said programs need higher versions of that packages. I don't want to e.g. upgrade GTK3, its new version is horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) or compile the programs yourself. Because libraries used in Ubuntu are upgraded each version, you can't just install programs compiled for 16.04 to 14.04. you can use backports because they are compiled against your 14.04 libraries but if your programs do not exist in backports repositories then you have to compile them yourself.

This is because programs in 16.04 repositories are compiled against newer libraries which ship with 16.04 and does not exist in your 14.04 distribution. To be able to use new programs compiled against newer libraries, `apt-get` wants to replace old libraries with new ones. But you are saying that you do not want to upgrade your old libraries.

So, to avoid this. You must either upgrade to 16.04 (upgrades all libraries at once) or compile newer versions of the programs in your 14.04 system manually. This way the programs you wan't will be compiled against your old version libraries, so you hopefully will not need to upgrade them (unless programs do not compile because they do not support those old versions anymore!)

If you choose the compile option, you can follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

In my opinion you should upgrade to 16.04. Because you can not stay in 14.04 forever anyway. It will eventually become obsolete. Have a look at [some alternatives](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours) You may like Ubuntu MATE desktop perhaps, it looks more old-fashioned.

Comment: Why to compile the program to require the newest possible libraries? -.-

Comment: You want newest program version using old libraries. You have to compile the program against old libraries. You can't use program compiled against new libraries when your system have old libraries. This is why apt wants to replace a lot of stuff(old libraries) when you try to install a program from 16.04 repositories. Because 16.04 has new libraries so programs compiled for 16.04 require new libraries. In my opinion, you should probably upgrade to 16.04 completely.